# How to sign a pdf with XML signature

Tags: java, timestamp, itext, bouncycastle, xml-signature

I'm working on an Java application for digital signature and timestamping PDFs, using iText and BouncyCastle.

The problem is that we have to make a timestamp with a XML signature received from a web service.

Anyone know if this is possible to do it?.

Kind regards.

Comment: Well, you can start by reading my book: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and then continue with ISO-32000-1 or the PAdES standards. You'll notice that you're mixing things that aren't provided in the standard, making your requirement kind of impossible, as if you'd try to drive a square peg into a round hole. XML signatures are only supported in PAdES-5. Adobe Acrobat/Reader doesn't support those signatures yet and your PDFs probably aren't fit for PAdES-5, so please drop the XML signature thing and rethink your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In a nutshell:*

Integrated PDF time stamps require RFC3161 time stamps (if time stamping is desired at all).

*In detail:*

In case of time stamped signatures according to [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (which still is the current PDF standard), the signature container can contain:

> Time stamp information as an unsigned attribute (PDF 1.6): The timestamp token shall conform to RFC 3161 and shall be computed and embedded into the PKCS#7 object as described in Appendix A of RFC 3161. The specific treatment of timestamps and their processing is left to the particular signature handlers to define.
>
> *(section 12.8.3.3.1)*

In case of the document time stamps according to the PAdES LTV profile from [ETSI TS 102 778 part 4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.02_60/ts_10277804v010102p.pdf) extending the standard, the document time stamp value

> shall be the TimeStampToken as specified in RFC 3161 [6].
>
> *(Annex A.2)*

Thus, for you to be able to create interoperable PDF time stamps, your service must provide RFC 3161 time stamps.

[ETSI TS 102 778 part 5](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277805/01.01.02_60/ts_10277805v010102p.pdf) allows XML time stamps, but they can only be used

- for XAdES signatures of signed XML documents embedded in PDF containers *(section 4)* and
- for XAdES signatures on XFA Forms *(section 5)*.

Neither of those stamps the PDF as such.

Comment: Hello guys, Lot's of thanks Bruno Lowagie, @mkl for helping me understand better the differents concepts about pdf signatures.Now I understand everything much better. Kind regards.